# Aggregate Rating Schema Showing Outside of Product Schema

Tags: schema

I'm encountering an issue with the Schema markup on our website, specifically regarding aggregate rating schema.

I've noticed that the aggregate rating schema is showing outside of the product schema for the URL https://www.igp.com/flowers/mumbai,

I've used the Schema Validator tool to confirm t issue.

Could you please help me troubleshoot this issue? I'd appreciate any insights or guidance on how to ensure the aggregate schema is correctly nested within the product schema for the affected URL.

Aggregate Rating Schema Showing Outside of Product Schema